# Display modal from external file

Tags: javascript, jquery, bootstrap-4, bootstrap-modal

I have some bootstrap modal in my website and these modals invokes by image button. I want to simply the main file so I want the modal data called from external files. But It didn't works as I expected. First paragraph of code is my original code to call modal. Second part is my new code with assigned id and class. Last part is my load function. Thanks for your help!

I have tried to use js load function to load the modal data from external files but It has no effect when I click the image.

```
**Original Code**
<div class="col-md-2 col-4"> \\Original Code to invoke modal
<button type="button" class="playerbutton" data-toggle="modal" data- 
target="#three"><img src="images\123.png" class="squadplayerimg"> 
</button>
<!--  player Modal -->
<div class="modal fade" id="three" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria- 
labelledby="three" aria-hidden="true">
<div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
<div class="modal-content">
  <div class="modal-header">
    <h5 class="modal-title">Player Info</h5>
    Main modal body and data ........
  </div>

**New Code**
 <div class="col-md-2 col-4">
 <button type="button" class="playerbutton test"><img 
 src="images\123.png" class="squadplayerimg"></button>
 <div id="three" class="modal fade text-center">
 <div class="modal-dialog">
  <div class="modal-content">
  Get data from outside files
  </div>
  </div>
  </div>

 </div>

**js load function**
$('test').load("newmodal.html #three",function(){
$('#three').modal();
});
```

Answer (score 1):

You can try something like that:
Feel free to change it to your liking.

```js
$("#somediv").click(function() {
  opendialog("http://jsbooks.revolunet.com/");
});

function opendialog(page) {
  var $dialog = $('#somediv')
  .html('<iframe style="border: 0px; " src="' + page + '" width="100%" height="100%"></iframe>')
  .dialog({
    title: "Page",
    autoOpen: false,
    dialogClass: 'dialog_fixed,ui-widget-header',
    modal: true,
    height: 500,
    minWidth: 400,
    minHeight: 400,
    draggable:true,
    /*close: function () { $(this).remove(); },*/
    buttons: { "Ok": function () {         $(this).dialog("close"); } }
  });
  $dialog.dialog('open');
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8"> 
    <title>Dialog with page</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.1/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css">
    <script type="text/javascript" src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.1.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.1/jquery-ui.js"></script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div id="somediv">
      Click me!
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```